SQLite: блокировка файла базы
Был полностью рабочий проект — а стал нерабочим. Я пытался его конвертировать файл в .exe, потом после того как прилетела ошибка, удалил все новые папки из папки проекта — и он перестал работать.
Проект полностью построен на SQL-таблицах. После данного инцидента при любой попытке запроса к БД, программа падает с ошибкой:

Sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked


А файл этот точно никто не использует в данный момент, никакая программа?

Он используется только в коде. По крайней мере, я использую его только там. Может быть компиляция в .exe что то сломала или делает постоянные запросы ?
